# Removing repeated letters in a set of rows on PostgreSQL 8.3

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.3

I have a query that returns a set of rows with a combination of the letters  `A`, `E`, `I` and `L`. That combination are Portuguese mneumonics for `Alterar`, `Excluir`, `Incluir`, and `Listar`. The column value can vary between `A`, `AE`, `AEL`, `AELI`... `L`, `LI`, `LIA`, `LIAE`.

In the example illustrated below I would like to be able to get a unique string with all repeated letters removed. So the result would be `AELI`, a merge of all rows.

[image]

My first attempt was using the combination of the functions `array_to_string` and `array_agg`.

```
select array_to_string(array_agg(colmn), '') from mytable;
```

then I used the `regexp_matches` function for matching only one character of the same letter, but with no success, because returned `AELA`.

```
select regexp_matches('AELAEILI', '[?AEIL][?AEIL][?AEIL][?AEIL]');
```

[**Here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6f8ed/4) the examples explanated above.

---

### **Note**

That problem explanated here is a piece of a great sql instruction. This [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6f8ed/4) is my effort of simulating my real problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can be achieved by using the `regexp_split_to_table` postgresql function.

From the docs:

> Split string using a POSIX regular expression as the delimiter. See
>   Section 9.7.3 for more information.

So, if have the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE example_table (col TEXT);

INSERT INTO example_table(col) VALUES
  ('AEL'),
  ('A'),
  ('E'),
  ('I'),
  ('L'),
  ('LI');
```

The result of the query `SELECT regexp_split_to_table(col, '') as col`

will be

```
col
A
E
L
A
E
I
L
L
I
```

After managing to split the words like that, filtering the duplicates is pretty simple by adding the DISTINCT statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(regexp_split_to_table(col, '')) as col
  FROM example_table
```

The result of this query is going to be

```
col
A
E
I
L
```

At the end we can convert the result rows to a single string with the following code:

```
SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(col),'') FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT(regexp_split_to_table(col, '')) as col
  FROM example_table
) temp_table;
```