# Get Distinct Value in a List/Cell in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

it happens that I am having this type of data structure and trying to eliminate the duplicated values under `Type` in Postgres.

Initial Table

```
Index   Type
1       A, B
2       A, A
3       B, B
```

Expected Table

```
Index   Type
1       A, B
2       A
3       B
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values to begin with. Do you have a chance to fix the broken data model?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing repeated letters in a set of rows on PostgreSQL 8.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50867514/removing-repeated-letters-in-a-set-of-rows-on-postgresql-8-3)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a CTE to split the comma separated values into rows using [`STRING_TO_ARRAY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html) and [`UNNEST`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html); then put the distinct values back together again using [`STRING_AGG`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

```
WITH Types AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT Index, UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(Type, ', ')) AS Type
  FROM Data
)
SELECT Index, STRING_AGG(Type, ', ') AS Type
FROM Types
GROUP BY Index
ORDER BY Index
```

Output:

```
Index   Type
1       A, B
2       A
3       B
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/48e5f5/6)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach that doesn't use aggregation over the entire table:

```
SELECT Index,
       (SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT t, ', ')
        FROM UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(Type, ', ')) AS t
       ) as types
FROM Data;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8b8c88b23a83b19e948c7d5f259058bf) is a db<>fiddle.

Although I would expect Avoiding the outer aggregation would be a win on performance on larger data sets, it doesn't appear to be so.

Comment: Interestingly `explain analyze` seems to suggest that the CTE approach is faster, and it gets even more relatively fast the more data that is added. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f881c6ac1b4f64228bf576cd6fd2f161

Comment: @Nick . . . Very interesting.  Thank you for investigating.  It is always fun to learn new things.

Comment: Yeah I must say I was surprised by the result - the query execution plan is a lot shorter for your approach. I guess there is a lot of internal optimisation going on in the planning stage.